# Where did Drogon fly off to?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne", after we see Jon

> murdering Daenerys, Drogon shows up, burns down the Iron Throne, takes Daenerys' body and flies off.

Where did he fly off to?

Comment: I really hope he takes her to Dragonstone and burns her in Targaryen rites.

Comment: Probably a pretty basic we don't know answer here...

Comment: Off to where writters do not have to concider him anymore.

Comment: I like to think he's flying off to where he hatched, and where Danny was reborn in the flames of Drogo's funeral Pyre.

Comment: He flew of to $equelland

Comment: He flew to Nangijala, the land of the dead, and took the name Katla.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't know, he just flies off somewhere east. We could speculate though that he could be going to Dragonstone or Meereen, places where he has some affinity and where he's been with Dany. He could also be going to the ruins of Valyria where the dragons are from. However, the truth of it is that we simply don't know.

> **Bran:** And Drogon? Any word?
>
> **Sam:** He was last spotted flying east, toward...
>
> **Bronn:** The farther away, the better.
>
> **Bran:** Perhaps I can find him.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne"</sub>

Comment: Hopefully he gets a spinoff.

Comment: if he gets a spinoff, I also want a spinoff about the adventures of ghost. And another one about Arrrya the pirate.

Comment: "toward..." Valyria, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

We simply don't know. It could be Valyria or any one of the free cities. Maybe the great grass sea where he was born. Balerion did that after all with Aerea Targaryen. He was born in Valyria. Drogon was born in the Dothraki sea.

If he returns to the Bonfire it would be symbolic of Dany and Khal Drogo being reunited as was seen in the vision in the house of the Undying.